# Add column with TRUE/FALSE if id matches in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, concatenation, inner-join

This is my current query :

```
select * from modeles JOIN marques ON modeles.marque_id = marques.marque_id
```

I would like to add a column to the returned data called "isActive" and it should contain TRUE or FALSE (or 1 / 0) depending on whether another table (modeles_scrape) contains a row where modeles.display_name = modeles_scrape.marque

So, expected result :

```
modele_name;modele_id;marque_name;marque_id;isActive
"Captur";1;"Renault";1;TRUE
```

I undertand this is a question that has been asked already but the solutions I have found join the modeles_scrape table, which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select mo.*, ma.*,  -- better enumerate the columns you want here
    exists (select 1 from modeles_scrape ms where ms.marque = ma.display_name ) as isactive
from modeles  mo
inner join marques ma using(marque_id)
```

Comment: @Akina Thought I had already, my bad. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT modeles.*,
       marques.*,
       modeles_scrape.marque IS NOT NULL isActive
FROM modeles 
JOIN marques ON modeles.marque_id = marques.marque_id
LEFT JOIN modeles_scrape ON modeles.display_name = modeles_scrape.marque
```

If `modeles_scrape` may contain more than 1 matched row then add DISTINCT to avoid duplicates in output.

---

> The OP said he specifically did not want a join. Whilst I agree that this is the most natural way to go, I think the OP is looking for EXISTS with a sub select. – Jonathan Willcock

No problems.

```
SELECT *,
       EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM modeles_scrape
                WHERE modeles.display_name = modeles_scrape.marque) isActive
FROM modeles 
JOIN marques ON modeles.marque_id = marques.marque_id
```

And yes, this may be more effective when `modeles_scrape` table is too wide.

Comment: The OP said he specifically did not want a join. Whilst I agree that this is the most natural way to go, I think the OP is looking for `EXISTS` with a sub select.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Updated.